# How to implement segmented control inside submit button in iOS (Xcode)?

Tags: ios, swift, loops, button, segmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control for gender inside the submit button, however, it gives an error stating:

"Cannot assign value of type "String" to type "UISegmentedControl!" "

Does anybody know how to properly code segmented controls inside a button so that when the user clicks on a submit button, it displays the selected gender on the page?

EDIT: The question I am trying to answer is:

"Implement an App that include input fields for Name, Address and a Stepper (for Age) and two Segmented Controls (for “Male/Female” and “Enrolled/Not Enrolled”). When the user clicks on a submit button, it displays the message on the page such as Hello Name, Address: Address, Age: Age, Gender: Male/Female, Status: Enrolled/Not Enrolled. "

Here is my coding:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var nametxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var age: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var addresstxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var status: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var gender: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    age.wraps = true
    age.autorepeat = true
    age.maximumValue = 100
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
    var txtname : String
    var txtaddress : String
    txtname = nametxt.text!
    txtaddress = addresstxt.text!


    if self.gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        gender = "male"
    }

    if self.gender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
        gender = "female"
    }

    display.text = "Hello " + txtname + ", " + "Address: " + txtaddress  
    + ", " + "Gender: " + gender

  }
 }
```

Comment: Why you put segment control to button? you can get action of Segment control it self only.

Comment: That is the task given by the tutor...When the user clicks on the button, it is supposed to display the result from the segemented control

Comment: Obviously, `gender = "male"` and `gender = "female"` are non-sensible code. Could you mention what are you aiming to do?

Comment: So here is the complete question.. "Implement an App that include input fields for Name, Address and a Stepper (for Age) and two Segmented Controls (for “Male/Female” and “Enrolled/Not Enrolled”). When the user clicks on a submit button, it displays the message on the page such as Hello Name, Address: Address, Age: Age, Gender: Male/Female, Status: Enrolled/Not Enrolled. "

Comment: This question is created by lack of Swift and UIKit knowledge... I suggest you to go through Apple documentation and figure out what SegmentControl API has to offer. Also please I discourage you from using force-unwraps anywhere. It's bad practice...

Comment: Actually aha I got no choice but to answer the question as it is...it is actually created by our lecturer and even the unwrap code is by him. Our lecture notes did not help with this question and neither did I find much information online. Thanks for your help! I will definetly look into those :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this error occur is simply described by the compiler :) Just use String instead of SegmentControl... gender is type SegmentControl so you cannot concatenate it with other strings...

use `titleForSegment(at:)` to get the right string value

`display.text = "Hello " + txtname + ", " + "Address: " + txtaddress

    + ", " + "Gender: " + gender.titleForSegment(at: gender.selectedSegmentIndex)`

And you can get rid of the conditions above...

Other option is to set new private property inside the `IBAction`

```
@IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any) {
    // Fixed your codestyle and semantics as well
    let txtname = nametxt.text ?? "missing name"
    let txtaddress = addresstxt.text ?? "missing address"

    let txtgender = gender.titleForSegment(at: gender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    display.text = "Hello " + txtname + ", " + "Address: " + txtaddress  
    + ", " + "Gender: " + txtgender

  }
 }
```

`https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol/1618561-titleforsegment